# Ionic Pass Promise to RootParams

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I have a tab view in Ionic which needs to wait for some data to load to pass to the params.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="usersPage" tabTitle="Users" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="profilePage" [rootParams]="{id: currentUserId}" 
       tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In my Tabs Controller I set the user Id like so:

```
export class TabsPage {
    usersPage: any = UsersPage;
    profilePage: any = ProfilePage;
    currentUserId:number;
    constructor(public identity: Identity) {
        identity.getCurrentUser().then(u => 
           this.currentUserId = u.id)   
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to wait for the Current User To resolve before so I can be assure the Tab will always pass the appropriate id?

Comment: I believe it will be better to store UserId on `localStorage` after user logged in your app. So you'll always have access.

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive I am storage the returns a promise or loads it If it hasn't been loaded yet